# Java script to populate pages in quick launch

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am working with a wiki site. I was wondering if there is a way to populate the pages created from the page library to be automatically added to the quick launch?. Otherwise each time I will have add them manually from the navigation.

If so is there a sample code I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Refer below code sample of how to add link to quick launch using javascript.

This is the working code. You can modify this code according to your need and use it directly.

```
var quickLaunchNodeCollection = null;
var oNewNaviNode = null;

function addNavigationNodes() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    if (context != undefined && context != null) {

        var web = context.get_web();

        //this.navigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();
        this.quickLaunchNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();

        // Set properties for a new navigation node.
        this.oNewNaviNode = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
        oNewNaviNode.set_title("NewNavigationNode");
        oNewNaviNode.set_url("http://www.google.com");

        oNewNaviNode.set_asLastNode(true);
        this.quickLaunchNodeCollection.add(oNewNaviNode);

        context.load(this.quickLaunchNodeCollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(addNavigationNodesSuccess, addNavigationNodesFailed);
    }
}

function addNavigationNodesSuccess() {
    alert("New node added...");
}

function addNavigationNodesFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Here is the link where I originally posted this answer -- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219086/add-new-link-to-quick-launch-navigation/219094#219094

Comment: Thank you rohith. How will I refer pages in page library to this. I see it adds google .com to the quick launch

Comment: Can I use a content editor or script editor and use this code directly?

Comment: @Rinu You can use this code directly in content editor. But you will have to pass page Title and Url to this code manually..

Comment: Is there some way we can automate adding title and URL. Will the web variable able to get the contents from the pages library and populate using a for loop or something

Comment: I copied and pasted the above code directly in to the script editor but it doesn't seems to work